# Can I recreate a unit from a single drive RAID1 in a 3ware Raid controller?

Tags: linux, raid, hard-drive, 3ware

I have a broken server and a broken disk on that same server on a RAID1 setup.

I need to setup this same RAID unit, now on a new server, and from only 1 drive (since the other is broken).

I moved the drive to a new server, also with 3ware controller, and it's recognized as "U?"

I could of course create a unit but I am afraid some data on disk may be overridden and I don't want to risk that.

Side question: Can I access the filesystem (ext4) data by just plugging the disk to normal sata controller or does the raid controller add some meta data that makes it unreadable in such a simple setup? (I didn't try this yet)

Answer (score 1):

Seriously, you need help regardless RAID controller state without giving it's name?!

You have very big chances to recover the data with just pluging one of the mirrors to another computer, assuming that raid state was consistent. If you worry about it you can do non-destructive copy byte-by-byte to other media to create disk image and operate on that. You can use linux dd command from sysresccd: http://www.sysresccd.org/Download for instance.

In all cases with controllers in RAID1 mode I was able to recover the data. You are very lucky here.

Comment: By name I assume you mean model?

Comment: You are correct. Sorry.